# How do I set a variable in all programming modes?

Tags: customize, programming, tabs

I'd like `tab-width` to be set to 2 in all programming modes.  I use `prelude` (which might be one of the problems), but I have this in my `custom.el` (which is sort of the analogue to `.emacs`):

```
(setq my-tab-width 2)
(setq standard-indent my-tab-width)
(setq tab-width my-tab-width)
(setq c-basic-offset my-tab-width)
(setq js2-basic-offset my-tab-width)
(setq web-mode-attr-indent-offset my-tab-width)
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset my-tab-width)
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset my-tab-width)
```

How can I avoid all the duplication?

Comment: If you want to set the **default** value of `tab-width` **everywhere**, use `setq-default`. If you want to set the value of `tab-width` in all modes that inherit from **`prog-mode`** then do what @dan suggested.

Comment: @Drew: Oops, I didn't mean to write `'(` but `(setq` instead. I'll change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Nearly) all [programming modes inherit](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/05/prog-mode-the-parent-of-all-programming-modes/) from [`prog-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Major-Modes.html), so you can set the variable in `prog-mode-hook`:

```
(defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
  (setq tab-width 2))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-mode-hook)
```

(Note that you could use a lambda instead, but this way you'll have an easier time removing the hook if you ever want to do so.)

Comment: Can you explain the `#'my-prog-mode-hook)` syntax? Thanks!

Comment: @Avery: see [get in the habit of using sharp quote](http://endlessparentheses.com/get-in-the-habit-of-using-sharp-quote.html), or check out the manual for more details.