# Variable assignment for programming modes not working

Tags: hooks, prog-mode

I want to set the variable `truncate-lines` to `t` in order to have truncated lines, but only in programming modes. So, following [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19456/how-do-i-set-a-variable-in-all-programming-modes), I put the following code in my configuration file:

```
(defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
  (setq truncate-lines t))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-mode-hook)
```

My problem is this does not work, because `truncate-lines` is still `nil` when I start Emacs in `fortran-mode` (for example). The `lambda` version of the above code gives the same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Inspect the value of `prog-mode-hook` with `F1 v` to make sure the function has been added to the hook.

Comment: And then make sure that some mode that derives from `prog-mode` does not, itself, change the value of `truncate-lines` to `nil`. You can also use `M-x debug-on-entry my-prog-mode-hook` to follow along and see what happens when it is invoked.

Comment: The variable `prog-mode-hook` contains `my-prog-mode-hook`, so I guess it is ok. Then when I `M-x debug-on-entry my-prog-mode-hook`, a list of functions that are run is displayed, but after a quick look, I haven't find any occurrence of `truncate` in their definition. But something came to my mind: I have `(global-visual-line-mode 1)` in my config file, could it be the culprit?

Comment: `(global-visual-line-mode 1)` was most probably the problem. Thanks a lot to both of you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility to achieve what I wanted is to have

```
    (add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
```

in addition to

```
    (defun my-prog-mode-hook ()
      (setq truncate-lines t))
    (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'my-prog-mode-hook)
```

which wraps long lines in `text-mode` while truncating them in programming modes.

Beware not to have any `(global-visual-line-mode 1)` instruction elsewhere in the config file, otherwise the above hooks don't work (the lines are always wrapped).

Comment: More precisely the hooks *do* work (`my-prog-mode-hook` successfully sets `truncate-lines` to `t`), **but** the globalized mode `global-visual-line-mode` subsequently triggers `visual-line-mode` (during `after-change-major-mode-hook`, after the mode hooks have run), which sets `truncate-lines` to `nil`, effectively undoing the earlier change.

Comment: @phils Thank you for the precision.